# Microsoft Azure Mobile authentication with Google provider SDK in Android

Tags: android, azure, authentication

I am currently testing Microsoft Azure and the App Service/Mobile Apps feature using a native Android app and C# on the back end.

I started with the Getting Started application (ToDo) as the base app and now I am trying to enable Authentication using the https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-authentication-overview/ page and Google as the provider.

So far I have

- created a Google project with a OAuth Web client
- the authorized redirect uri set there is: https://.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/google/callback
- in the Azure portal and the App Service instance I have enabled Authorization/Authentication
- the "Action to take when request is not authenticated" option is set to "Allow Request"
- For the Google Provider I have set the Client Id and Client Secret

In the Android app I am using the GoogleApiClient class to let the user select a Google Account. Also I get the ID token and the Server Auth Code

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestEmail()
            .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.server_client_id))
            .requestServerAuthCode(getString(R.string.server_client_id))
            .build();
    mScopes = gso.getScopeArray();

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this, this)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .build();
```

Once the user picks up an account I retrieve the token and code and then I ask for an access token using the GoogleAuthUtil class. After I get the access_token I try to exchange it with an App Service token (authenticate2 method)

```
private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {
    Log.d("", "handleSignInResult: " + result.isSuccess());

    if(result.isSuccess()) {
        final GoogleSignInAccount account = result.getSignInAccount();

        final String idToken = account.getIdToken();
        String serverAuthCode = account.getServerAuthCode();

        mSignInButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mGoogleUserText.setText(account.getDisplayName());
        mGoogleUserText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        prefs.edit().putString("idToken", idToken).commit();
        prefs.edit().putString("serverAuthCode", serverAuthCode).commit();

        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
                try {

                    StringBuilder scopesBuilder = new StringBuilder("oauth2:");
                    for(Scope scope : mScopes) {
                        scopesBuilder//.append("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/")
                                .append(scope.toString())
                                .append(" ");
                    }

                    String token = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(ToDoActivity.this,
                            account.getEmail(), scopesBuilder.toString());

                    return token;
                } catch (IOException | GoogleAuthException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ToDoActivity.this);
                prefs.edit().putString("accessToken", result).apply();

                authenticate2();
            }
        }.execute();
    } else {
        mSignInButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mGoogleUserText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}

private void authenticate2() {
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    String idToken = prefs.getString("idToken", null);
    String serverAuthCode = prefs.getString("serverAuthCode", null);
    String accessToken = prefs.getString("accessToken", null);

    JsonObject json = new JsonObject();
    json.addProperty("access_token", accessToken);
    json.addProperty("id_token", idToken);
    json.addProperty("authorization_code", serverAuthCode);

    ListenableFuture<MobileServiceUser> loginFuture =
            mClient.login(MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.Google, json);

    Futures.addCallback(loginFuture, new FutureCallback<MobileServiceUser>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(MobileServiceUser result) {
            createTable();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
            Log.e(TAG, t.getMessage(), t);
        }
    });
}
```

So I am using the MobileServiceClient.login() method to send back to the server the access_token of the user in order to get back an Azure session.

Nevertheless, this call fails and I get back a MobileServiceException:

com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.MobileServiceException: You do not have permission to view this directory or page.

Any ideas what am I missing here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well this is more than embarassing :-)

I first tried to "manually" verify the id_token using the Google tokeninfo endpoint:
https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?id_token=

but I was getting a generic error that didn't give a lot of info.

Then I used the Google API Java client library and created a small test to verify my token (more info here: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/backend-auth)

That test was failing as well and I realized that the reason for that was the expiring time of my token which was smaller than the current time. And this was happening because my emulator time was not correct!

When I set the "correct" timezone everything worked as expected.

Sorry for the post guys. You can use the code here as a template and don't forget to check your emulator time :-)